# find min and max values and create columns for these for each unique identifier (grouping element) in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following dataset:

```
MC <- c(rep("OS000348",8), rep("OS000361",13), rep("OS000375",5))
ASN <- c(rep(2,8), rep(3,5), rep(2,8), rep(3,5))
Dia <- c(870,"NA", 867.3, "NA", "NA", 890.3,"NA","NA",871.2,"NA",868.7,"NA",866.2, "NA",
"NA",851,"NA","NA",842,"NA","NA",880,860,851.8,"NA",841)

df <- data.frame(MC,ASN,Dia)

df
```

I want to find for each MC, min and max Dia values and arranged in the resulting table as shown below:

```
MC          Dia     Min_Dia Max_Dia
OS000348    870     867.3   890.3
OS000361    871.2   841     871.2
OS000375    880     841     880
```

What I am trying is using dplyr package and the following:

```
result1 <- 
  df %>% 
  group_by(MC) %>% 
  arrange(MC) %>%
  slice(c(1, n())) %>%
  mutate(minmax = c("Min", "Max")) %>%
  gather(var, val, Dia) %>%
  unite(key, minmax, var) %>%
  spread(key, val)
```

But I am not getting the table, the way I want it (2nd table above).

Can there be alternatives?

Comment: Don't input as `"NA"`, input as `NA` instead. The `aggregate` function will work nicely: `aggregate(Dia ~ MC, data = df, FUN = function(x) c(head(x,1), min(x, na.rm = T), max(x, na.rm = T)))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, you need to input NA's as `NA` not `"NA"`, otherwise R reads it as character vector and you can't use the `min()` function. This code produces the desired output:

```
MC <- c(rep("OS000348",8), rep("OS000361",13), rep("OS000375",5))
ASN <- c(rep(2,8), rep(3,5), rep(2,8), rep(3,5))
Dia <- c(870,NA, 867.3, NA, NA, 890.3,NA,NA,871.2,NA,868.7,NA,866.2, NA,
         NA,851,NA,NA,842,NA,NA,880,860,851.8,NA,841)

df <- data.frame(MC,ASN,Dia)

library(dplyr)

df <- df %>%
  group_by(MC) %>%
  mutate(minDia=min(Dia, na.rm=T), maxDia=max(Dia, na.rm=T))
```

And use this if you only want to keep one observation of MC:

```
df2 <- df %>%
  group_by(MC) %>%
  mutate(minDia=min(Dia, na.rm=T), maxDia=max(Dia, na.rm=T)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  distinct(MC, minDia, maxDia)
```

Comment: thanks for such a quick response. it shows an Error: ‘min’ not meaningful for factors

Comment: This error message would not present itself if you follow @yoland's advice in the first sentence.

Comment: Make sure that "DIA" is an numeric vector. If not use `df$DIA <- as.numeric(df$DIA)`. And yes, the "NA" issue needs to be resolved before ;-)

Comment: please check for `df2` this has only one col for MC and not `Min_Dia` and `Max_Dia`

Comment: it has 5 cols in my results. did you run the exact code? `distinct()` only removes rows and not cols by definition, so this shouldn't happen

Comment: I just cross checked... in first, I got `df` with 5 cols (and NAs) and in second, I was supposing to get Distinct `MC` but it return only 1 col in `df2` with distinct MC (i.e. OS000348, OS000361 OS000375)

Comment: just added `distinct(MC, minDia, maxDia)` to the second one... it worked!

Comment: thank you! that's still a bit odd. I remember having some trouble with distinct() and factors. maybe it does something else, than what i think it does? i should probably use unique() until i figure that out